# Correct way to link to prawnto partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn, prawnto

I'm trying to access the prawnto documentation but their website is down. Does anyone know what's the correct way to link to a prawnto partial in my rails app. Here is how I linked to the main pranwto file, namely, `show.pdf.prawn`:

```
<%= link_to hotel_shell_path(@hotel_shell, :format => 'pdf') do %>
  <%= icon("file-pdf-o", "", class: "", href: '#') %>
<% end %>
```

`show.pdf.prawn` is rendering partials for a lot of other `pdf.prawn` files with the `partial!` method that prawnto uses.

However, I don't wanna link to `show.pdf.prawn` this time. I wanna link to one of the partials.

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn this what you need i guess

Comment: To render a partial you need to have an action that does the rendering